# Share audio file

Tags: android-studio

I have an url link that has a audio file and i want to share audio file through my app. But i'm getting error saying that "sharing failed, please try again"

```
String sharePath =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "https://www.admin.bhajandarshana.com/audio/BDIMG15654188363967.mp3";
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath);
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("audio/*");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            Toast.makeText(MusicPlayerActivity.this, "" + uri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
```